# PHP email is not sending after adding .on('success.form.fv', function(e) in formValidation

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, email, jquery-form-validator

I used `formValidation` framework on my bootstrap form, validations work perfectly and email successfully sent to mail address, But after adding these lines to form validation:

```
.on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Prevent submit form
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form     = $(e.target),
                validator = $form.data('formValidation');

            // Show the modal
            $('#helloModal')
                .modal('show');

            $form
                .formValidation('disableSubmitButtons', false)  // Enable the submit buttons
                .formValidation('resetForm', true);             // Reset the form
        });
```

Email is not sending anymore. Everything work perfectly but I think the PHP part of email is not processing because of above code.

FULL Jquery formvalidation code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#defaultForm').formValidation({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {

            firmname: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Firm name is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            contactname: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Contact name is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            phone: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Phone number is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            address: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    }
                }
            },            
            optradio1: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please choose one of the option'
                    }
                }
            },
            optradio2: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please choose one of the option'
                    }
                }
            },
            optradio3: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please choose one of the option'
                    }
                }
            },
            optradio4: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Please choose one of the option'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).on('success.form.fv', function(e) {
            // Prevent submit form
            e.preventDefault();

            var $form     = $(e.target),
                validator = $form.data('formValidation');

            // Show the modal
            $('#helloModal')
                .modal('show');

            $form
                .formValidation('disableSubmitButtons', false)  // Enable the submit buttons
                .formValidation('resetForm', true);             // Reset the form
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is your php code which send mail? and what error you are getting?

Comment: There are no errors, before adding the end part of validation, email was sending perfectly after submitting the form. But after adding the .on('success.form.fv', function(e) ..... email is not sending